# How add footer and header files to a java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

How to add add a consistent header and footer to a java servlet?

Case in question:

1. servlet.java, display "hello world" text
2. Goal is to display

   ```
   header.html
   Servlet.java
   Footer.html
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need a third element:

template.jsp ( or a Template.java Servlet)

It would look like (JSP):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>${param.title}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/header.jsp"/>

    <jsp:useBean id="test" class="Demo.MyClass" />
    <%
       MyContent content = new MyContent();
       content.getHtml();
     %>

    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
</html>
```

or the servlet equivalent.

If using the Servlet approach the primary receiving Servlet would open the two header and footer files, and return their contents with the wrapped content in-between.

See [this tutorial](http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet_tutorial_:_Using_JSPs_to_create_header,_footer_area,_formatting,_and_basic_CSS_for_bookstore#Last_but_not_least_footer.jsp_and_header.jsp) for a more detailed approach (using JSP pages).  You can extrapolate what would need to be done with Servlets from the patterns presented.